# How to center labels inside a C3.js piechart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, c3.js

The labels inside each piechart arc are at the edge. I want to make the text bigger using css (.c3-arcs text selector), but the text gets cut off. Is there a way to make the labels centered within each arc?

Here's a [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/meyahayasi/edit?js,output)

[image]
[image]

Comment: That will be tricky actually to manipulate with css as they are rendered within the SVG draw...

Comment: @Pogrindis Is there another way besides css? I've been going through their docs, but unable to find any option to modify these positions.

Comment: it seems they use `d3.format()` method for this, but there doesn't seem to be any 'out of the box' solution to your question..

Answer (score 0):

Coworker came up with a solution using [text-anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor), which isn't perfect, but moves the labels closer to center.

[image]

```
.c3-chart-arcs text { 
    text-anchor: start !important;
}

.c3-target-Large text {
    text-anchor: end !important;
}
```

Updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tubezozeje/1/edit?css,js,output)